# Importing Pillow module in Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to install a lambda function as shown on this blog...

https://www.obytes.com/blog/image-resizing-on-the-fly-with-aws-lambda-api-gateway-and-s3-storage

I followed these steps, uploaded the zip file and getting an error.

```
git clone https://github.com/obytes/resize_s3_images.git

cd resize_s3_images/

wget https://pypi.fcio.net/packages/14/41/db6dec65ddbc176a59b89485e8cc136a433ed9c6397b6bfe2cd38412051e/Pillow-6.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

unzip Pillow-6.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl && rm Pillow-6.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

zip -r resize_s3_images.zip .
```

When I try to test the function:

> {   "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'resize_s3_images':
>   cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/var/task/PIL/**init**.py)",
>   "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install pillow package with pip at this directory like this.

```
pip install Pillow -t .
```

Then remove existig zip and make again.

```
rm -rf resize_s3_images.zip

zip -r resize_s3_images.zip .
```

Import Image from pil like this

```
from PIL import Image
```

If you still have problem then use lambda layers or move code into '/tmp/dependencies/' directory using `os.system('cp <folder_name> /tmp/dependencies/)`

Comment: Python version of build server should match with Lambda version. I managed it using this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Getting Internal Server Error now https://azqvbborn5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stag1/resize

Comment: Did you get the Pillow library from Linux or Windows? Lambda will work with the linux version only.